# I have having issues implementing procedural terrain generation on my three js project

Tags: javascript, three.js

Hello friends https://github.com/IceCreamYou/THREE.Terrain This is a great Library for procedural I want to add the procedural terrain generation in my code

Code goes here

```
  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,0.01, 100000);
    camera.position.set(50, 10, 50)
      camera.position.z = 10
       
       
    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    renderer.setClearColor(0xcccccc, 1.0);
    renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap; // default THREE.PCFShadowMap
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
 
  const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera,renderer.domElement );
    controls.screenSpacePanning = true;
    const sceneMeshes = [];
    
    const axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper( 1000 );
    scene.add( axesHelper );
    axesHelper.position.y = 0
    
    const shadowLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.6);

    // Set the direction of the light  
    shadowLight.position.set(150, 350, 350);
    // Allow shadow casting 
    shadowLight.castShadow = true
    // define the visible area of the projected shadow
    shadowLight.shadow.camera.left = -400;
    shadowLight.shadow.camera.right = 400;
    shadowLight.shadow.camera.top = 400;
    shadowLight.shadow.camera.bottom = -400;
    shadowLight.shadow.camera.near = 1;
    shadowLight.shadow.camera.far = 10000;
        // define the resolution of the shadow; the higher the better, 
        // but also the more expensive and less performant
    shadowLight.shadow.mapSize.width = 2048;
      shadowLight.shadow.mapSize.height = 2048;
        // to activate the lights, just add them to the scene
    scene.add(shadowLight);
 
  
const animate = function (){ 
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );               
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        };
        
animate();
```

**Normal Scene**
*please help me for my project*

Comment: *What* issues do you have? What is your concrete question?

Comment: Implementing a procedural terrain generation on my Scene how to do it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a live example based on your code using the default approach of `THREE.Terrain` for generating a terrain mesh:

```js
 const scene = new THREE.Scene();

 const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 100000);
 camera.position.set(0, 250, 1000)


 const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
 renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
 renderer.setClearColor(0xcccccc, 1.0);
 renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap; // default THREE.PCFShadowMap
 renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
 document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

 const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
 controls.screenSpacePanning = true;
 const sceneMeshes = [];

 const axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper(1000);
 scene.add(axesHelper);
 axesHelper.position.y = 0

 const hemiLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffff, 0x444444, 0.6);
 scene.add(hemiLight);

 const shadowLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.8);

 // Set the direction of the light  
 shadowLight.position.set(0, 1000, 0);
 // Allow shadow casting 
 shadowLight.castShadow = true
 // define the visible area of the projected shadow
 shadowLight.shadow.camera.left = -400;
 shadowLight.shadow.camera.right = 400;
 shadowLight.shadow.camera.top = 400;
 shadowLight.shadow.camera.bottom = -400;
 shadowLight.shadow.camera.near = 1;
 shadowLight.shadow.camera.far = 10000;
 // define the resolution of the shadow; the higher the better, 
 // but also the more expensive and less performant
 shadowLight.shadow.mapSize.width = 2048;
 shadowLight.shadow.mapSize.height = 2048;
 // to activate the lights, just add them to the scene
 scene.add(shadowLight);

 //

 // Generate a terrain
 var xS = 63,
   yS = 63;
 terrainScene = THREE.Terrain({
   easing: THREE.Terrain.Linear,
   frequency: 2.5,
   heightmap: THREE.Terrain.DiamondSquare,
   material: new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
     color: 0x654321
   }),
   maxHeight: 100,
   minHeight: -100,
   steps: 1,
   xSegments: xS,
   xSize: 1024,
   ySegments: yS,
   ySize: 1024,
 });
 // Assuming you already have your global scene, add the terrain to it
 scene.add(terrainScene);


 const animate = function() {
   requestAnimationFrame(animate);
   renderer.render(scene, camera);
 };

 animate();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.131.3/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.131.3/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three.terrain.js@2.0.0/build/THREE.Terrain.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sir facing error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Linear' of undefined

Comment: Then you are probably importing `THREE.Terrain` not correctly. Please share a live example that shows what you are doing.

Comment: I just made my projects repository gameUI.html is the main file

Comment: Live link: https://raw.githack.com/Joker-pyc/project-Survival/main/GameUi.html

Comment: Try importing `"THREE.Terrain.min.js` right after the import of `three.js`. In any event before `world.js`.

Comment: Sir I imported "THREE.Terrain.min.js right after three.js but I don't see it working the errors still there what can be the possible causes

Comment: You now import `css/index.css`, `js/index.js` and `jworld.js` but all these directories and files do not exist. You should import `world.js` instead.

Comment: Yes that's actually because I didn't know how to make different directories on GitHub but I have made different directories in the local storage